# can't purge java bin installation

Tags: java, purge

I tried doing this:

```
 sudo dpkg -P package_name sun-java6-bin
```

and it gives me this

```
dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching package_name
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of sun-java6-bin:
 sun-java6-jre depends on sun-java6-bin (>= 6.26-1lucid1) | ia32-sun-java6-bin (>= 6.26-1lucid1); however:
  Package sun-java6-bin is to be removed.
  Package ia32-sun-java6-bin is not installed.
dpkg: error processing sun-java6-bin (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sun-java6-bin
```

What should I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can paste this on terminal: `sudo apt-get purge sun-java6-jre sun-java6-bin`

Comment: Or you can use `aptitude`, which I have found to be better at solving dependency problems.

Comment: I upvote for aptitude too, but you will have to install it first because since 11.04 it doesn't come from default.